# PUT request doesn't update - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, put, django-serializer

I'm trying to build a todos app using django-rest-framework and when I send PUT request to change the content of the task, the content is still the same. It seems that the serializer.save() is not working as I expected.
Here are the code:

> views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response 
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view 
from .models import Note
from .serializers import NoteSerializer

@api_view(['PUT'])
def updateNote(request, pk):
    note = Note.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = NoteSerializer(instance=note, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Note(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

> serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import Note


class NoteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = '__all__'
```

I'm learning django so this is kinda new to me. I had searched for this problem but I'm kinda new to django so I don't understand these answers much.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
   def updateNote(request, self, pk):
   note = get_object_or_404(Note.objects.all(), pk=pk)
   serializer = NoteSerializer(instance=note, data=request.data, partial=True)

   if serializer.is_valid():
     serializer.save()

   return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but it's saying that "TypeError: updateNote() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' ", what should I do next

Comment: sorry self comes first like this def updateNote(self, request, pk)